# How i can display the table component i made in angular to the index file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

[this is the appointment component i have which contain a table of appointments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpFvz.png)

[and this is where i'm calling the appointment component][2]

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <card cardTitle="Appointments" isCollapse="true">
    <appointment></appointment>
    <!-- <div echarts [options]="AnimationBarOption" [loading]="showloading" theme="dark"></div> -->
  </card>
</div>
```

[this is my component typescript file][3]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "appointment",
  templateUrl: "./appo.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./appo.component.scss"],
})
export class AppoComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Array<any>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
      { PROFILEPHOTO: "Steve", DOCTORNAME: "Jobs", APPOTIME: "@steve" },
      { PROFILEPHOTO: "Simon", DOCTORNAME: "Philips", APPOTIME: "@simon" },
      { PROFILEPHOTO: "Jane", DOCTORNAME: "Doe", APPOTIME: "@jane" },
      { PROFILEPHOTO: "Larry", DOCTORNAME: "Thornton", APPOTIME: "@larry" },
      { PROFILEPHOTO: "Hiver", DOCTORNAME: "Choe", APPOTIME: "@hiver" },
    ];
  }
}
```

[and this is the component html file][4]

```html
<div class="raw">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a href="appointments.html" class="btn btn-primary float-right"
          >View all</a
        >
      </div>
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <table class="table table-borderless table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Profile</th>
              <th>Doctor Name</th>
              <th>Timing</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngfor="let item of data ;let index= index">
              <td>{{item.PROFILEPHOTO}}</td>
              <td>{{item.DOCTORNAME}}</td>
              <td>{{item.APPOTIME}}</td>
              <td>
                <a
                  href="appointments.html"
                  class="btn btn-outline-primary take-btn"
                >
                  Take up</a
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

normally it should work like this but it just shows an empty table of one row on the screen.
i'll really appreciate any help guys !!

Comment: post your code as text, not links to images with code.

Comment: oh sorry, should i post it again !!

Comment: Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62761350/edit) this post to include the code as text

Comment: i hope it's more clear like that !!

Comment: I'd try removing tbody, and check console logs to see if something weird is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine

I have replicated ur example
u have a typo it should be *ngFor

[image]